# How to change value of array element to 5 if it's equal to 4 and inform number of changes?

Tags: java, arrays

The array `x={2, 3, 4, 4, -5, 4, 6, 2}` the resulting array is to be `x={2, 3, 5, 5, -5, 5, 6, 2}`, and the number of changes reported with a message like `"The number of changes is 3"` printed on screen.

```
public class anArray {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        int [] x = {2, 3, 4, 4, -5, 4, 6, 2};

        for (int i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(x[i]);   
        }    //currently only I am able to print whole array element
    }
}
```

Comment: I would take a look into [if statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) if I were you.

Comment: `x[i]` is just an `int`. Use it how you would with any other if statement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public class anArray {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        int [] x = {2, 3, 4, 4, -5, 4, 6, 2};
        int count =0;
        for (int i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
            if (x[i] == 4) {
                count++;
                x[i]=5;
            }
        }
        system.out.println("...."+count);
    } //main()
} //anArray
```